# Correlate events with extrinsics in a utility.batch call in Polkadot

Tags: query, extrinsic, events

In Polkadot and Kusama emitted module events has the phase property so we can correlate them with the extrinsic that triggered that event but I can not do the same when the extrinsic is included in a `utility.batch` (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#batchcalls-veccall) extrinsic (as far as I know all the events are related to the utility.batch call so you can not correlate them individually).

Is there a way to correlate an event with the related extrinsic included in a `utility.batch` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `utility.batch` call emits events which allow you to organize which extrinsic events are coming from each extrinsic.

Between each call, you should see an `Event::ItemCompleted` after an extrinsic as successfully completed, or a `Event::BatchInterrupted` if one of the items in the batch caused the whole batch to stop. After the whole batch is done, you will see `Event::BatchCompleted`.

You can see an example of that here: https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/8997424-2

[image]

Here you can see `ItemCompleted` between the crowdloan contribution (the first extrinsic), the memo being updated (the second extrinsic).

So it is just a matter of using these as delimiters, and organizing the events to the appropriate sub-batch call.